# Cisco Anyconnect VPN (Linux) won't launch

Tags: linux, opensuse, cisco-vpn-client

Using OpenSUSE 13.2 (64-bit), I recently installed the Cisco AnyConnect VPN. It shows up in my applications list, and I can try to launch it, but after about 10 seconds of the "loading" spinning icon, the application disappears from the task manager. How can I troubleshoot the application failing to launch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Attempting to launch the VPN through

```
/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpnui
```

returned an error message that `libpangox` was not available. Installing that library with

```
zypper inst libpangox-1_0-0
```

corrected the issue.

Comment: For the current version (1.12.4), `inst` is an unknown command. It must be `in` or `install`. But then it gives a "Warning: No repositories defined. Operating only with the installed resolvables. Nothing can be installed."

Comment: Instead, simply use `apt-get install libpangox-1.0`